# Can't redefine tabstop, softtabstop and softwidth after syntax detection

Tags: options, filetype-ruby, softtabstop, retab

I've a vim:

```bash
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, собрано Apr  8 2020 14:10:43)
```

and I tried to redefine tabstop, softtabstop and softwidth values for a file after detection of its syntax. I.e. I have a file `file.rb` with the comment:

```ruby
# vim:set sw=4 sts=4 ts=4 et:
```

But the values of the tabstop, softtabstop and softwidth staty the same as they were defined during file type detection, i.e. `sw=2 sts=2`.

When I forcely try to define the same options at my `.vimrc`, as:

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

The values say the same, and when I tap a tab key, the cursor is moved to 2 points, instead of 4, during editing `file.rb`.

So, the question is how to properly change the options even after the file type detection, but when I wish not to fix the vim files manually?

Comment: Do you have the `'modeline'` option disabled? What does `:verbose set modeline?` tell you? If it's disabled (Vim says `nomodeline`), then Vim will ignore the modeline from your files with the overrides...

Comment: Also... Do you prefer to do this override through modelines on your `*.rb` files? Or do you prefer to create local overrides so that Vim will use 4 space indent (overriding the filetype default of 2) for every `*.rb` file, regardless of a modeline? Please [edit] your question to include the additional information.

Comment: I have no preferences to redefine, that options, i have tried to change with .vimrc or the modeline, but no effect. But for my projects currently I use modelines